# Sitecore Intallation, Presentation details error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

On my local sitecore 66 installation, when going on any random page presentation > details > edit controls the second popup (the edit one) throws the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Description: An unhandled 
exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review
the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in 
the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an 
instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be 
identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor.DeviceEditorForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any other information in the stack trace or in the logs? Is this a clean install of Sitecore 6.6, an existing project or an upgrade? Are you using any Shared Source modules?

Comment: @EdS. This is Sitecore specific, probably not something the OP has coded themselves, it may be misconfiguration of config or some missing files.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about configuration, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine sitecore upgrade installation from 6.4 to 6.6. 
The important part in the error message was the error location

> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.DeviceEditor

. Running a compare between a standard sitecore 6.6 installation and my local installation I discovered that the file sitecore\shell\applications\layout\deviceeditor.xml was outdated. Replacing the file with the correct version resolved the problem.

Comment: Great.. better if you can share more details on this, This post can prove helpful to people while upgrading to Sitecore 6.6

Comment: Easiest way, download the Sitecore zip from SDN, extract and compare your installation with this folder with something like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). I've seen some recent issues on dev machines related to something different, there is no one size fits all.

Comment: The somehow cryptic error gives a good hint about the path on the sitecore installation that's creating the problem